# Sort by comparable Bean property in Java 8

Tags: java

Is there a shorter way to sort by a comparable property using Java 8 streams than this pattern?

```
collection.stream()
    .sorted((a,b) -> a.getProp().compareTo(b.getProp()))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you could use [method reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) for this:

```
collection.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getProp));
```

Comment: Great! This looks quite idiomatic.